# Annoying indentation bug with ES6 multiline string using js-mode or js2-mode

Tags: indentation, js2-mode

I am using js2-mode right now.
I am working on a .js file that contain a ES6 multi like string like this:

```
Vue.component("comment", {
    props: {
        comment: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    template: `this is a multiline string,
it should be aline to the top!
`
});
```

How to fix the indent problem in the template at the end?
(tab is not working inside the string, and the two ` should be aligned)

Comment: This indentation behavior makes sense, as your string would otherwise contain potentially unwanted spaces. Lines inside of multi-line strings aren't indented for that reason. You could try using something like `align-regexp` to align these lines manually.

Comment: Ok but then it's really annoying to write nested html template (have to use space manually) because tab is not working inside the string.

Comment: Have you looked at `web-mode` or `mmm-mode`?

Comment: Yes web-mode does seems to do the job well! I am amazed about how much usefullness this pakage cover for webdev.